# How to customise content in material-table (React)?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table, mui-datatable

I want to add an icon in front of every item corresponding to its data in one column. Currently, I'm just using a JS array to display the static data but I can't customize it.

Using this right now:

```
<MaterialTable
title="Title"
columns={this.state.columns}
data={newDataTable}
options={{
  selection: true
}}
options={{
  search: false,
  sorting: true
}}
actions={[
  {
    icon: () => <Checkbox />,
    tooltip: 'checkbox'
  },
  {
    icon: () => <InfoIcon />,
    tooltip: 'info',
    onClick: (event, item) => {
      this.setState({
        isOpen: true,
        selectedItem: item
      });
    }
  }
]}
```

/>

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using: https://github.com/mbrn/material-table.

Before you pass the data to the table, you can add the icons like:

```
const newData = newDataTable.map((value) => ({...value, firstColumn: <SomeIcon />}));
```

and add a column with: `{ title: "", field: "firstColumn" }"`.